# HTTP ERROR 500 mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

I try to insert some data but i get HTTP ERROR 500 dont know why.I saw the problem starts with when i prepare the query.I try to insert mutiple rows from a txt file.

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "****", "***");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $contents = file_get_contents("cars.txt");
    $pollfields = explode(',', $contents);

    $query = "INSERT INTO table (`name`) VALUES (?)";

    $zz = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    $zz ->bind_param("s", $bb);

    $mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
    foreach ($pollfields as $bb) {
        $zz->execute();
    }
    $zz->close();
    $mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```

Comment: `$mysqli` or `$conn`?

Comment: Don't understand, $mysqli i think i don't know exact were is the issue

Comment: Do you understand that you have `$conn` and `$mysqli` variables in __your code__? Do you understand difference between them?

Comment: not so much i , i am in the procesor of learning

Comment: Okay, where is `$mysqli` __defined__? Where is `$conn` __defined__?

Comment: i see now, i try and works but now the problem is it jump pages in phpmyadmin it don't insert all the data correctly do you know why ?

Comment: you can anwer the question if you want tot confirm it

Comment: No, I don't know why.

Comment: Can u test it ? really need it, i have lot's o data to insert and i see it skip a loat

Comment: I can't and I won't test you code. Make an effort, do it yourself. Error checking with mysql is here http://php.net/mysqli_error. If below is your answer - then you forgot to change `$mysqli` in `->query('COMMIT')` line.

Comment: i ask because i don't now were to start i change all the $mysqli the problem is i jumps page i phpmyadmin  i have like 1-30 then 43-53  110-150 434-753  like that

Comment: it excuting to fast

Answer (score 0):

i need to defined it

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "****", "***");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $contents = file_get_contents("cars.txt");
    $pollfields = explode(',', $contents);

    $query = "INSERT INTO table (`name`) VALUES (?)";

    $zz = $conn->prepare($query);

    $zz ->bind_param("s", $bb);

    $conn->query("START TRANSACTION");
    foreach ($pollfields as $bb) {
        $zz->execute();
    }
    $zz->close();
    $mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```